# anchors click function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, anchor

This code:

```
a = document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.de')
a.click()
```

works in chrome. It open www.google.de as expected. But in firefox it does nothing.
Why and how can it be made to work?

I am using firefox 40.0.3 on ubuntu linux 15.04.

Comment: Do you ever actually add  the newly created anchor element to the page DOM?

Comment: No, I don't. I want this to happen in the background and not appear on the page.

Comment: It seems that firefox won't execute the click event when the element not attached to the body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.de');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Answer (score 5):

Firefox probably doesn't open the link because you never add it to the DOM.

You could add the element to the DOM and use css `display:none` to hide it from the page.

However, a more standard approach would be to either use the javascript [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method or `window.location.href` depending on your desired behavior.